# Carpetas HDPI - MDPI - XHDPI etc

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imagen

Me gustaría saber qué resolución deberían tener mis imágenes para estas diferentes carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que solo tengo 1 imagen que es de `400px X 400px`, entonces al tener por ejemplo una pantalla chica , las imágenes no caben bien y salen cortadas.

¿Cuál sería la medida correcta de mi imagen para cada una de estas medidas? Aparte de esto, ¿Android automáticamente me tomara la imagen de alguna de estas carpetas al detectar que, donde se está ejecutando, es una pantalla pequeña?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debieras pegarle un vistazo a [Compatibilidad con diferentes pantallas](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

### Extracto del link:

Existe un conjunto de seis densidades generalizadas:

```
ldpi (baja) ~120 dpi
mdpi (media) ~160 dpi
hdpi (alta) ~240 dpi
xhdpi (extraalta) ~320 dpi
xxhdpi (extra extraalta) ~480 dpi
xxxhdpi (extra extra extraalta) ~640 dpi
```

Dependiendo de cada dispositivo la resolución varia, por ejemplo:

```
320 dp: una pantalla típica de teléfono (240 x 320 ldpi, 320 x 480 mdpi, 480 x 800 hdpi, etc).
480 dp: una tablet tweener como Streak (480 x 800 mdpi).
600 dp: una tablet de 7” (600 x 1024 mdpi).
720 dp: una tablet de 10” (720 x 1280 mdpi, 800 x 1280 mdpi, etc).
```

### Alternativa de utilidad

Con el siguiente código se puede escalar o reducir una imagen dependiendo de los parámetros que se le ingresen, podrías inferir según el tamaño de la pantalla que tamaño de imagen quieres.

```
public static Drawable resizeImage(Context ctx, int resId, int w, int h) {

          // cargas la imagen de origen
          Bitmap BitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                                                          resId);

          int width = BitmapOrg.getWidth();
          int height = BitmapOrg.getHeight();
          int newWidth = w;
          int newHeight = h;

          // calculas el escalado de la imagen destino
          float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
          float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

          // para poder manipular la imagen 
          // debes crear una matriz

          Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
          // resize the Bitmap
          matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

          // volves a crear la imagen con los nuevos valores
          Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                                                     width, height, matrix, true);

          // si queres poder mostrar la imagen tenes que crear un
          // objeto drawable y así asignarlo a un botón, imageview...
          return new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        }
```

### Tool web:

Permite hacer algunos assets y luego los copias en la carpeta de tu proyecto. Podría llegar a serte de utilidad en alguna ocasión.

[AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Comment: Es todo tan variado que busco una respuesta mas directa , ej mdpi -- 100x100 , la segunda tal x tal , gracias por la info  aunque ya lo habia visto y no me queda muy claro ,

Comment: Para una respuesta directa, deberías especificar un dispositivo. Como bien explica va por densidad de pixeles. Por eso se recomienda subir una imagen de gran densidad y Android Studio te genera el resto, en esas carpetas.

Comment: Lo que te refieres es que no necesito yo poner una imagen de x resolucion en cada carpeta sino que poniendola en la mas grande , por mas que yo entre a la ruta de las careptas y no vea imagenes android la trasforma ?

Comment: Resources > Image Assets - Ahí puedes elegir el tipo, cargas tu imagen y genera el resto, sino otra alternativa en subir la imagen tamaño normal y que haga el resize por código, si quieres te edito la respuesta y agrego el código.

Comment: Si por favor , seria de gran ayuda